# ExtJS (3.4): Update ToolTip for a Panel in a TabPanel

Tags: extjs, tooltip, extjs3, tabpanel

How do I change the tooltip for a panel located in a tab panel? Originally, I created a tooltip using the tabtip parameter of the panel constructor as the panel was added to the tabpanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grab the DOM element that represents your tab's tab strip. You can use [tabPanel.getTabEl(tabID)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.TabPanel-method-getTabEl) to get the strip element. You can then grab the `.x-tab-strip-text` span and set its `qtip` property.

```
// be sure to set your tab's itemId
var tabPanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
   items: [{
      title: 'one tab',
      tabTip: 'something',
      itemId: 'firstTabID',
      html: 'haha wooo'
   }]
});

// later...
// .getTabEl grabs the tabstrip DOM element
// Ext.get converts it to an Ext.Element
Ext.get( tabPanel.getTabEl('firstTabID') )
   // find its descendent span that contains the tab's title text
   .child('span.x-tab-strip-text', true)
   // and set the tool tip
   .qtip = 'something completely different!';
```

I'd never changed tab tooltips before so I dug around [the Ext.TabPanel source](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/source/TabPanel.html#Ext-TabPanel-method-initTab) looking at how they set it. I learned something too :)